# Export Angular page to static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web-applications, export

I would like to send an Angular9 application page via email as a static HTML.

I can create a screenshot or pdf of it using puppeteer, but I didn't find any solution to export a single page as a static HTML.

I tried to save the DOM with a headless browser, but many styling stuff was missing (so basically there was a black page with some text).

TL;DR:
How can I export an Angular app page as a static HTML

Comment: Could use [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to quickly get an express server to render out pages prerendered.

Comment: You can also take a look at [Scully](https://github.com/scullyio/scully)

Comment: both above works fine for this case